# Change model before model state validation ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm using foolproof library for dynamic attribute validation.

The model is as follows:

```
public class ProfileQuestion
{
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
        [RequiredIf("Isrequired", true, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }   
        public string Areacode { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        public List<ProfileOptions> OptionsList { get; set; }
        public bool Isrequired = false;
}
```

We have a list of question, some of the questions are required. If a question is required, then `Isrequired = true`. I'm setting `isrequired` flag before model state validation, but `ModelState.IsValid` is always false.

```
var mandatoryQuestions = objBusLayer.GetMandatoryQuestionIds(m);

foreach (ProfileQuestion question in Response)
{
    if (question.QuestionId == 2)
    {
        string date = question.Year + @"/" + question.Month + @"/" + 
question.Day;
        DateTime outdate;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out outdate))
        {
            question.Answer = date;
        }
    }

    if (question.QuestionId == 3)
    {
        question.Answer = question.Areacode + '-' + question.Zipcode;
    }

    if (mandatoryQuestions.Contains(question.QuestionId.ToString()))
    {
        question.Isrequired = true;
    }
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Encryption encObj = new Encryption();
    string decryptedExtPanelistId = encObj.DecryptText(e, password);
    objBusLayer.Register(decryptedExtPanelistId, m, Response);
    return RedirectToAction("Register", new { e = e, m = m, pg = pg + 1 });
}

ViewBag.pageId = pg;
ViewBag.extpnltid = e;
ViewBag.mid = m;

return View(Response);
```

I could not find the issue, can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Please please please sate my OCD by changing `Isrequired` to `IsRequired`... I can over look `Zipcode` and `Areacode` :D

Comment: i will change for sure :)

Comment: Setting the value in the controller does not affect `ModelState` (`ModelState` is set based on the request values before any of your code is executed). You need to make `Isrequired` a property (by adding `{ get; set; }` and then set it to `true` or `false` as required, and generate a form control for it so it gets posted back when you submit

Answer (score 3):

Try use combination of ModelState.Clear() and TryValidateModel().

```
ModelState.Clear();
TryValidateModel(Response);
```

Regards.

Comment: this return always true @krzysztofukl

Comment: Newer example: ModelState.ClearValidationState(nameof(Movie));  if (!TryValidateModel(Movie, nameof(Movie))) { return Page(); }
[Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation)